# How to remove underline in links in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress theme development.I tried well but not getting right .how to remove underline from links.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url')?>">
<h1 calss="vijay">
    <?php wp_loginout('www.google.co.in')?>
</h1>
```

css file.

```
h1{
    color:red;
    text-decoration: none;
}.
```

Comment: add anchor tag (a tag) css property.ex. a{color:red;text-decoration: none;}

Comment: you can add parent attribute like body, div,span  class name it will be override default style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperlinks are governed by anchor tags `<a>` hence you have to use a in 
your css link this

```css
 h1 a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

you can refer to [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

Answer (score 6):

I have just discovered that WordPress adds a `box-shadow`to some of its tags.

```
a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not the h1 that has the underline, it is the a tag sitting underneath it. So, try

```
h1 a{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
a{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Copy This code & past in Your CSS file

Answer (score -2):

The best option, tested and trusted is just to add this code in the customization tab.

```
a {  
   border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

And the error is gone.

Comment: This only works, if the underline is caused by a set border-bottom! Usually, it is caused by text-decoration: underline (which is also browser default style).